# Class matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

When I entered 2 matrices, the program stopped. It does not print the sum, even the words "Sum of 2 matrices" are not printed too. I don't know if this is all about allocation errors because when I use static arrays or vector, the result is correct. I don't know how to fix it. Hope everyone help pls! Thank a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Matrix
{
private:
    int** value;
    int row;
    int col;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int, int);
    Matrix(const Matrix&);
    Matrix operator + (const Matrix&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Matrix&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, Matrix&);
    ~Matrix(void);
};
int main(void)
{
    Matrix a, b, c;
    cout << "Input 1st matrix: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cout << "Input 2nd matrix: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << b;
    c = a + b;
    cout << "Sum of 2 matrices: " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
Matrix::Matrix()
{
    this->row = 0;
    this->col = 0;
    value = new int *[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        value[i] = new int[col];
    }
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                value[i][j] = 0;
            }
    }
}
Matrix::Matrix(int b, int c)
{
    this->row = b;
    this->col = c;
    value = new int *[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++)
    {
        value[i] = new int[col];
    }
}
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &a)
{
    this->row = a.row;
    this->col = a.col;
    value = new int *[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        value[i] = new  int[col];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                value[i][j] = a.value[i][j];
            }
    }
}
istream& operator >> (istream& ip, Matrix& a)
{

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Input rows: ";
    ip >> a.row;
    cout << "Input cols: ";
    ip >> a.col;
    a.value = new int* [a.row];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        a.value[i] = new int[a.col];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
        {
            cout << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << " : ";
            ip >> a.value[i][j];
        }
    }
    return ip;
}
ostream& operator << (ostream& op, Matrix& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
        {
            op << a.value[i][j] << " ";
        }
        op << endl;
    }
    return op;
}
Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix &a)
{
    Matrix tg;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
        {
            tg.value[i][j] = this->value[i][j] + a.value[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tg;
}
Matrix::~Matrix(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++)
    {
        delete[] value[i];
    }
    delete[] value;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the size of `Matrix tg` in your `operator +`? You are using default constructor.

Comment: when you use `std::vector` the result is correct, then why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I just want to get used to using pointer

Comment: ok, just be aware that a Matrix isnt something you would normally use an `int**` for in C++. Your conclusion from this exercise should be that this isnt a use-case for pointers ;)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Hmm I still don't quite get it, can you explain more pls?

Comment: As well as what @john says in the answer below you also need to implement `operator=`.  You are breaking the rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have followed you, it's still not right:((

Answer (score 0):

In this code how many rows and columns do you think `tg` has?

```
Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix &a)
{
    Matrix tg;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
        {
            tg.value[i][j] = this->value[i][j] + a.value[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tg;
}
```

It should be

```
Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix &a)
{
    Matrix tg(a.row, a.col); // make tg same size as a
    for (int i = 0; i < a.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.col; j++)
        {
            tg.value[i][j] = this->value[i][j] + a.value[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tg;
}
```